# elasticsearch normalizer is not working for the lowercase

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have created the below normalizer for the field `code` to query the elasticsearch based on both upper and lower case.

```
PUT my_index12
 {
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
    "normalizer": {
       "my_normalizer": {
       "type": "custom",
       "char_filter": [],
       "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
     }
   }
 }
},
"mappings": {
  "doc": {
    "properties": {
      "code": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
      }
    }
   }
  }
}
```

And am trying to search using wildcard query, am not getting any results, without normalizer am able to get with the uppercase, exactly how it is there in elasticsearch

```
get my_index12/_search
{ 
  "query": { 
  "wildcard": { 
  "code.keyword": { 
          "value": "*AB-7000-5000-Wk-21*" 
        } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Please find my index below

```
      {
        "_index": "my_index12",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "code": "ABCq123S"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index12",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "code": "AB-7000-5000-Wk-21"
        }
      }
```

If i try to do the mapping for `code.keyword`

```
"mappings": {
"doc": {
"properties": {
  "code.keyword": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
  }
}
```

am getting the below error while inserting documents into the index

```
    {
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "object mapping for [code] tried to parse field [code] as object, but found a concrete value"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "object mapping for [code] tried to parse field [code] as object, but found a concrete value"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Comment: You have no `code.keyword` field definition in your mapping.

Comment: @Val if i try to map `code.keyword` am getting error while am inserting document into the index `"object mapping for [code] tried to parse field [code] as object, but found a concrete value"` - updated in the question too

Comment: `code.keyword` must exist in your mapping **prior** to creating the index. Anyway, I was just saying that your query uses `code.keyword` which doesn't exist in your mapping. You should just use `code` instead of `code.keyword`

Comment: @Karthikeyan: Just to remove your confusion , keyword field gets generated for all default `text` (String) fields in ES. In your case it is not getting generated as you do not have "code" as a default text field.

Comment: @Richa - thanks for your clarification., how can i solve this issue. is there any thing wrong in my mappings ?

Comment: @Karthikeyan: As per @val's comment. Dis you try `GET my_index12/_search
{"query":{"wildcard":{"code":{"value":"*ab-7000-5000-Wk-21*"}}}}` with just `code` instead of `code.keyword`.

Comment: @Richa I tried, without `code.keyword` am not able to get records.

Comment: Its working only with `code.keyword` not `code`

Comment: It's funny since there's no `code.keyword` in the mapping. What do you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_index12`?

Comment: Sorry Val & Richa, its my bad., its working properly now.. Thankyou...